# Data Structure for caching (Key = DateTime, Value = decimal)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a function which calculates employee hours in a day. But, it's  slow because it considers carry hours and other things.

I figure I can optimize this by caching the hours in a day and only update on change.

I'm looking for something that can quickly do:

```
Set(date,hours)
HasHoursFor(date)
GetHoursFor(date)
```

What should I use for this?

I could use a `Dictionary`, but I am wondering if there is not some sort of hash way to set, get, and contains quickly.

Comment: Can you show us a bit more? What exactly is your input, wat output do you expect and what do these three functions actually do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `Dictionary<DateTime,int>` and cache the hours against the date, like so:

```
Dictionary<DateTime,int> dict = new Dictionary<DateTime,int>();

void Set(DateTime date, int hours)
{
    if (dict.Contains(date)) dict.Remove(date);

    dict.Add(date.Date,hours);
}

bool HasHoursForDate(DateTime date)
{
    return dict.Contains(date.Date);
}

int GetHoursForDate(DateTime date)
{
    return dict[date.Date];
}

Set(DateTime.Now,8);
```

I normalise the date so that's its JUST the date and doesn't care about the time part, otherwise that would throw off the comparison. I'm also assuming you have whole hours otherwise you might want to change `int` to `double` etc.